# PostgreSQL showball algorithm does not work on synonyms

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, config, synonym, snowball

I created custom config and synonyms for this config.
Here is my `synonym_custom.syn` file contents

```
gate    door
```

These are the creation scripts:

```
CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION icons (copy='english');

CREATE TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY my_synonym (
    TEMPLATE = synonym,
    SYNONYMS = synonym_custom
);

ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION icons
    ALTER MAPPING FOR asciiword, asciihword, hword_asciipart,
                  word, hword, hword_part
    WITH my_synonym, english_stem;
```

Now, when I create vector it does not create lexem for the word `gates`

```
postgres=# select to_tsvector('icons','door doors gate gates');
      to_tsvector
-----------------------
 'door':1,2,3 'gate':4
(1 row)
```

as you see it changes the words `door`, `doors` and `gate`, but not `gates`. Instead the snowball algorithm worked on `gates` and created lexem `gate`.
How to force postgresql to pass the result of synonym throw snowball algorithm. I know, that synonym dictionary has priority over snowball. As a workaround I can add all modifications of the `gate` word into `synonym_custom.syn`, but I have 3,500 words with synonyms like this. So it's not a solution in my case.